# Concatenate two Ranges in SQL

Tags: sql

Here is my table,

```
      ID#   | DocBreak |  Old Document Range | New Document Range
     00001  |   D      |  00001 - 00005   
     00002  |   N      |  00001 - 00005          
     00003  |   N      |  00001 - 00005     
     00004  |   D      |  00001 - 00005 
     00005  |   D      |  00001 - 00005 
     00006  |   D      |  00006 - 00006
     00007  |   N      |  00007 - 00007  
     00008  |   N      |  00008 - 00008
     00009  |   D      |  00009 - 00011           
     00010  |   N      |  00009 - 00011           
     00011  |   D      |  00009 - 00011           
     00012  |   N      |  00012 - 00012
```

Results should be:

```
      ID#   | DocBreak |  Old Document Range      | New Document Range
     00001  |   D      |  00001 - 00005           | 00001 - 00005 
     00002  |   N      |  00001 - 00005           |           
     00003  |   N      |  00001 - 00005           |    
     00004  |   D      |  00001 - 00005           | 00001 - 00005
     00005  |   D      |  00001 - 00005           | 00001 - 00005
     00006  |   D      |  00006 - 00006           | 00006 - 00006|00007 - 00007|00008 - 00008
     00007  |   N      |  00007 - 00007           | 
     00008  |   N      |  00008 - 00008           | 
     00009  |   D      |  00009 - 00011           | 00009 - 00011
     00010  |   N      |  00009 - 00011           | 
     00011  |   D      |  00009 - 00011           | 00009 - 00011|00012 - 00012  
     00012  |   N      |  00012 - 00012           |
```

Would be nice if someone could help me figure out how I can generate New Document Range from columns DocBreak and Old Document Range.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be equally nice if you told us your database engine and what the criteria for the new document range is.

Comment: @DanBracuk 'the criteria' is in the New Document Range column in the OPs post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

New [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ec22d/53)

```
With AllDocs As (
  Select ID, DOCBREAK, OLDDOCUMENTRANGE 
  From Test),

UniqueDocRanges as (
  Select DISTINCT AllDocs.ID, AllDocs.DOCBREAK, t.OLDDOCUMENTRANGE
  From Test t
  INNER JOIN AllDocs on t.Id >= AllDocs.ID
                    AND t.ID < (Select Case When min(ID) Is not Null Then min(ID) else (select max(ID) + 1 from Test) End from Test where Test.Id > AllDocs.ID and Test.DocBreak = 'D')  
  )
select AllDocs.*, Case When DocBreak = 'N' Then '' Else STUFF((
    SELECT ' | ' + t.OLDDocumentRange
    FROM UniqueDocRanges t
    WHERE t.Id = AllDocs.ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,3, '') End AS ConcatenatedDocs
from AllDocs 
;
```

The above is similar to the example below but I find more readable and has the added bonus of removing duplicates. AllDocs is as it says a list of all Docs (D&N). UniqueDocRanges is taking the list of AllDocs and finding the group of Docs for each ID starting with a DocBreak-D upto the next D with all the N's inbetween. The DISTINCT operator in UniqueDocRanges removes the duplicates. Finally the last statement takes the list of all docs, joins in our groups and then concatenates them to form our CONCATENATEDDOCS column.

Hope that works for you!

---

Spent quite a bit of time on this. Enjoy!

```
SELECT tOuter.*, Case When DocBreak = 'N' Then '' Else STUFF((
    SELECT ' | ' + t.OLDDocumentRange
    FROM Test t
    WHERE t.Id >= tOuter.ID
    AND t.ID < (Select 
                 Case When min(ID) Is not Null Then min(ID) 
                 else 
                    (select max(ID) + 1 from Test) 
                 End 
                from Test where Test.Id > tOuter.ID and Test.DocBreak = 'D')
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,3, '') End AS ConcatenatedDocs
FROM Test tOuter
```

I have created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ec22d/39) demonstrating. It assumes you are using SQL Server. If you aren't you can use a similar technique but swap out the concatenation for something your RDBMS uses.

It is essentially doing a correlated sub query for every row in the table and getting all the rows up to the next row where DocBreak = "D". All the rows in between are concatenated using the FOR XML PATH('') trick with |. The Stuff command gets rid of the first unneeded pipe.

Comment: Thank you Sarin! I will test this out in SQL.

Comment: Hi Sarin, I don't have much programming experience so please forgive me for asking but how would I alter the code to remove duplicative values in a row. Example: 00001 - 00005 | 00001 - 00005 | 00001 - 00005 or 00009 - 00011 | 00009 - 00011.

Comment: I need to know what type of database you are using before I start investigating other methods?

Comment: Hi Sarin, we're using SQL server/ SQLExpress.